# Font difference in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have some app in heroku with free acc. In this app I use nodejs+gm and write some text via gm and myriadprobold.ttf on .jpg image. All is ok at my local machine(ubuntu): font is bold as I want.

But at production(heroku) font isn't bold, seems it's regular. Why?
command $ locale show the same as at my local and heroku.

Any ideas?

UPD:
I try another font, tahomabold - the same issue, I believe that this is not font issue

Answer (score 0):

holy guacamole!) I don't know why, but relative path not work, I used path.resolve() and issue is gone